# TYPO3 no database to select on the list

Tags: database, macos, typo3, mamp

i have problem installing the typo3 version 7.6.4. theres no database in the dropdown menu to select even though i created one in the phpmyadmin. beloq is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: did you provide your DB username, passwort and host correctly?

Comment: May be a permission problem. If you e.g. create a database using a root user it may not be allowed to even see that database if you use a different db user with TYPO3.

Comment: i created the db on localhost with root user and has access to all privileges

Comment: If you provide username and passwort then should be show db in select option but If you are working in your local server then you can select second option "create a new database"

Comment: no i didnt provide a username and password. i just created the db and proceeded with the installation. on the username field (one step before the provided screenshot) i wrote the db name (i didnt recognise the "root" username) and it directed me to this page in which i cant even create a new database

Comment: ah its ok now. i had to login with username root and password root as well. thanks for the suggestions